# Wikipedia renders WkWebView and Safari differently on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, wkwebview

This problem is iPad specific.

When I use a WKWebView inside my app, its User Agent field is identical to the one sent by Safari. However, the page returned by Wikipedia to my App includes the standard Wikipedia side-bar. Safari on the iPad does not show the side bar.

I would like WKWebview to behave the same was as Safari. I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) instead Its behaviour is identical to Safari

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have accepted the answer. For future readers, I will point out that you cannot embed these pages in your own view - the documentation is explicit about this, so you can only use it as shown above - that is, by transitioning to a full screen view of the web page. There is a "Done" button in the view that, when pressed, returns the user to the presenting view. WKWebView does allow embedding, but, as I have discovered, looks different in some way that I have not figured out, to the Wikipedia server.